# twitter4J unable to get raw json when using search API

Tags: java, interceptor, twitter4j

```
ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
//...  set your keys
String queryString = "Trump";
Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(cb.build()).getInstance();
result = twitter.search(query);
List<Status> tweets = result.getTweets();
String json = TwitterObjectFactory.getRawJSON(s);
```

and I get :

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Apparently jsonStoreEnabled is not
>   set to true.

**Question 1:**
   I looked through the source code and looks like jsonStoreEnabled is set on ThreadLocal by a call to TwitterObjectFactory.registerJSONObject . I don't think search does that . Does it mean its impossible to get raw json when calling search API ?

**Question2:**
   How do I intercept a call made inside the API to TwitterBaseImpl.httpResponseReceived  to get the value of the field before its obscured by layers of the framework ?  preferably without AspectJ

Comment: why not just do it yourself before the request ?

Comment: `cb.setJSONStoreEnabled(true)` ?

Comment: Thanks  Seelenvirtuose !!!!!!!  spent alot of time on this ,even called ByteBuddy to the resque :)

Answer (score 0):

Seelenvirtuose is correct  , I forgot to do cb.setJSONStoreEnabled(true)